# Why the MediaPlayer do not work in Android?

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I have a problem on MediaPlayer's method : create().
                                                         (Version 2.3.3)

```
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer.create(this, musicIds[0]).start();
```

First line is Ok, but the second line is the point.
   The eclipse suggestions me "Change access to static using 'MediaPlayer'(declaring type)" and "Add @SuppressWarnings 'static-access' to on Create()".
   By the way, I take eclipse's suggestions........but still don't work.

Comment: Yes, MediaPlayer got the "start called in state 1" and "Error (-38,0)

Answer (score 1):

It may be suggesting you do something like this:

```
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, musicIds[0])
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Actually, I've done it.Orz   I could't hear any sounds from my device.

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, musicIds[0]);
mp.start()
```

On success, prepare() will already have been called and must not be called again.
Don't forget to call  mp.release() after you are done with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Eclipse's suggestions should be the subject for not working your code.

I will concentrate my attention on the way how the `MediaPlayer` is started. Beware that it may take some time until the song is initialized. So you better set the `onPrepared()` listener and call `start()` only when the mediaplayer is prepared.

```
mMediaPlayer.create(this, musicIds[0])
mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more complete example of how to wait for the media player to be ready to play and ensure that you are releasing the media player.  Without calling `mediaPlayer.release()` you may have problems on subsequent calls to the `MediaPlayer`.

```
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(context.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.notification_ring);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    });
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```